# WooCommerce, price not showing on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this site here:

http://artendijen.com/cart/

Can anyone tell me why the prices are not appearing on my cart page? do I have to enable something? I have my shipping set up, payment gateway is getting setup tomorrow.

Comment: do you have any other plugins / addons installed for woocommerce?

Comment: I have shippings addons, but the price on the cart page was not displaying even before I added the addons.